# How do I disable browsers too many redirection prevention?

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, firefox, redirect, browser

There is a  php file redirects to itself by incrementing $_GET['page'] value. For example, domain.com?page=1 redirects to domain.com?page=2 until page value is 500. After 20 redirection firefox gives following error.

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> this problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Other browsers give similar errorr. Is there any browser setting to disable too many redirection prevention?

Comment: I am not away of such a settings option. But I would like to ask a question: what is the goal behind that strange redirection strategy you implemented?

Comment: when too many requests are made to twitter api in one page,internal server error occurs. that's how I decrease the number of per page requests and get away from 500 error.

Comment: Oh dear. You are probably talking about twitter evaluating the referrer header of your requests. Please learn how to set those manually, either on client or on server side. That will save you a lot of hassle...

Comment: Do you think I receive internal server error because I send to many requests from the same referrer?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I indeed missed that detail. Though I do not understand that, actually. Why does the number of requests from a page lead to an internal error?

Comment: I did not understand why either. I just solved it like this.

Comment: Does that error 500 occur on your system or on the twitter system?

Comment: It occurs on my system. Although I set max_exec time to infinite, allocated 12 GB of ram to php and so on, nothing changed.

Comment: Hm, if that is an error on your system, then I would call that current strategy you are using not a "solution", but a cheap workaround, an extremely inefficient one. Why don't you understand and solve the issue instead? What does your http servers error log file say what the issue is?

Comment: I've tried everything that I could think of. error log file does not show anything regarding that 500 error...

Comment: That would be _very_ surprising. There has to be a specific reason, a http 500 is generated if the php engine throws an uncatchable error. That is logged. And it definitely is possible to make hundreds of background requests within a single request, done that many times myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using javascript's window.location, problem is solved.